# Use web.config with php

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-config

i have windows hosting and website is in php. So i asked the hosting company where i can find the .htaccess file. and they said there is no .htaccess file in windows hosting i have to use web.config file to do website configuration.

I tried this simple code on my web.config but i got 500 - Internal server error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>


  </system.web>
  <rewrite>
    <rule name="rule 1c" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([a-zA-Z]+)$"  />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?category={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rewrite>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the web.config that I use to hide index.php, hope this will help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect index.php" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="index\.php/(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="\?{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rewrite index.php">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hii thanks for your reply, but i got issue if use your code, i try another way because on index.php i also have catagory of the menus

here is the code

Its working when i write as : mysite.com/sport (mysite.com/index.php?category=sport), mysite.com/clothes (mysite.com/index.php?category=clothes) etc..

but when i write as mysite.com/index then it treated as mysite.com/index.php?category=index

```
    <rule name="Catagary" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([a-zA-Z]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />

            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?category={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Gallery" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                              </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="gallery.php?id={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>

         <rule name="RewritePHP">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```